# Jquery Trigger Event on Input

Tags: jquery

I am required to create an application that changes the colour of a Div from the input of a text box and remove the input when the colour is set. I have managed that using this function:

```
function setColor() {
var background = $("#colorText").val()
$("#light1").css({"background-color":background}).show();
$('#colorText').val("");
};
```

and called by:

```
$('#setColor').on('click', setColor);
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="light" id="light1"></div>
    <div class="light" id="light2"></div>
    <button id="setColor">Set Color</button>
    <input type="text" id="colorText"></input>
```

But I have been told I HAVE to use .trigger. I have spent a while researching this task but cannot seem to find out how to do it.
I guess the change in the text box needs to trigger an event called setColor which changes the colour of the Div to the user input.

Thank you for your help

Comment: And why should you do that, did they give a reason? If this works for you, why change it? Using `on('click',...)` is in fact a trigger function, more info [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: This is the specific wording, but in person i was told it HAS to be .trigger.... 'Create and register a callback function with the top light div for events of type “setColor”. The setColor event provides an extra parameter which defines a colour. The callback function should set the background colour of the top light div to the given colour. '

Answer (score 0):

If your code works the way it is, don't change it.
If you have to change it because it is a requirement, read this:

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger()
>   executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event
>   were triggered naturally by the user:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/